# Installing ungit failed

Tags: node.js, git, ungit

I have some errors while intalling ungit with NPM. Check out this logs. Im on Win7 Pro x64.

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ungit\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts\node_modules\negotiator\lib\charset.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ungit"
npm ERR! cwd Z:\save\Personnel\user\test_git
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ungit\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts\node_modules\negotiator\lib\charset.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ungit\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts\node_modules\negotiator\lib\charset.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add a little explanation as to what you were trying to do, etc? Very unlikely anybody can help you without more context

Comment: Just launch the following command : npm install -g ungit
I tryed on other PC i have and no errors chown.